# How Jmeter handles LDAP Referral mechanism

Tags: jmeter, ldap, referrals

I am trying to do a LDAP mod operation through Jmeter. Expected behavior - Jmeter would hit server A which in turn would hit server B. Actual modification operation would happen at server B. Server B would complete the operation and give response to server A which in turn would respond to Jmeter.

Now the issue is, Jmeter is always getting the "Referral" response message. However, manually we are able to change the password after hitting server A from different remote server.

Could you someone please suggest how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this has been resolved. Just in case you are still wondering, @Rohan , my understanding is that you run jmeter on the command line:

```
$ jmeter -Jjava.naming.referral=true -n -t testplan.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Answer (score -1):

JMeter won't have specific behaviour of its own. You will need to tell it to follow referrals by setting [`java.naming.referral`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap-gl.html#referral) property appropriately in the `jndi.properties` mechanism defined in the documentation for the JNDI LDAP provider, which you should already have in place for your application if you expect it to behave that way.

Comment: how to include jndi.properties file in Jmeter. Do we need to directly put it inside lib folder?

Comment: can you please explain through one example?

Comment: You will already be putting a `jndi.properties` file in the root of your application JAR file. That's all that's required.